# Do I need to install or input a code to use @keyframes on CSS?

Tags: css, keyframe

Is there a code I have to put in or install a file so that my @keyframes will work in my CSS file? In my editor the @keyframe is grayed out and doesn't work.

Comment: @ridecar2 im using extplorer, a joomla plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a difference between syntax highlighting in an editor, and actual interpretation by your browser.

Depending upon your editor, you may need to install a language pack to ensure that it will properly recognize the newer CSS3 attributes.

You will need to add vendor specific prefixes to your selectors, for them to be understood by your browser

```
@-webkit-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-ms-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```

Learn more about keyframes in css3 http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/webkit-keyframe-animation-syntax/:

Comment: yes i tried using every browser prefix but they are all grayed out :C the editor is a ftp manager as well but has the editor when you open up the html or css file